# Import .aar library to android studio project via command line

Tags: android, android-studio

I am looking for a way to import .aar library into android studio project via command line.

Comment: Write a script in your favorite programming language, or a Gradle task, that adds the `compile` directive to `dependencies`. There is nothing built into the Android Plugin for Gradle that automates this for you, AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no option to include it via command line you need to edit your module's gradle file. However you could do this with sed.

Example:

```
sed -i -e "s/dependencies {/dependencies {\n    compile 'eu.rekisoft.android:lazyworker:1.0.0'/g" test.gradle
```